# PHP problems wiith decoding JSON

Tags: php, json

I have this data:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 19936953
    [name] => Zackaze
    [profileIconId] => 585
    [summonerLevel] => 30
    [revisionDate] => 1394975422000
)

$str = json_decode($data,true);


$row = (object) $str;
echo $row['name'];
```

I tried this code but it constantly gives this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: what if you try `echo $str['name'];`?

Comment: Pretty clear error message. You cast to `(object)`, but then treat it as an array with `$row['name']`.

Comment: Have a look at your `$row` with `print_r`, to see if it is an object or an array.

Comment: You explicitly tell `json_encode()` to return an array, then cast to object, then access as array. Even if this is code you found somewhere else, you should try and understand what it does.

Comment: Please explain to me the purpose of `$row = (object) $str;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have decoded your json as an associative array since you used true as second parameter so you can print it directly with scopes. If you need to decode as an object simply remove the second parameter, I think you will need to access it in another way though.

```
$str = json_decode($data,true);
echo $str['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

While the conversion to an object is unnecessary (as others have mentioned), that is not the cause of your error. You cannot access object properties using `$array['key']` notation. You must use `$object->property`.

Alternatively, you can remove the `$row = (object) $str;` line, and then you can access `$row` as an array.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of **json_decode** will convert the **Object** into a **Associative Array**. Just **remove the second argument** or change it to false and it will return a stdClass instead of a Associative array.

You can see the [Documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting like

```
$str = json_decode($data,true);
$str = array
(
    'id' => 19936953,
    'name' => Zackaze,
    'profileIconId' => 585,
    'summonerLevel' => 30,
    'revisionDate' => 1394975422000
);

$row = (object) $str;
echo $row->name;
```

Or a cleaner way

```
$str = json_decode($data);
echo $str->name;
```